# Предупреждение Сannot Destroy Paint Divace that is being painting

Tags: c++, qt, анимация

Мне необходимо сделать анимацию перемещения точки `QPoint` по траектории графика синусоиды. Рисую я график в функции `void QPaintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` Там же задаю начальное положение точки, которую нужно переместить и объявляю `QPainter`.

В конструкторе у меня объявлен таймер `startanimation`, который я запускаю по нажатии на кнопку. Таймер при переполнении выполняет этот слот

```
void MainWindow::paintEventWarm(){
animationpoint.setX((4*count));
animationpoint.setY(sin(animationpoint.x()));
count+=1;
update();
}
```

Где я устанавливаю новые координаты для точки, которую надо перемещать. Ошибок программа не выдает, но есть предупреждение

> Сannot Destroy Paint Divace that is being painting.

и таймер не переполняется.

Вот скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же вставить в `QPaintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)`

```
 painter->end();
```

И заново объявить его уже в функции `paintEventWarm()`, то таймер начинает работать, но в консоль каждый тик выдается сообщение

> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Помогите правильно сделать анимацию.

Метод paintEvent

```
    void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    painter = new QPainter(this);

painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QPen BlackPen (Qt::black);
BlackPen.setWidth(1);

QPen BluePen (Qt::blue);
BluePen.setWidth(2);



QPoint p1,p2;

int sh = width()/2;

p1.setX(0);
p1.setY(sh);

p2.setX(width());
p2.setY(sh);

painter->setPen(BlackPen);
//painter->drawLine(p1,p2);
painter->drawRect(0, 0, width(), height());

painter->setPen(BluePen);

// Строим синусоиду
p2.setX(0);
p2.setY(sh);
painter->setPen(BluePen);
for (int i = 0; i<bufer.size();i+=2){
    p1 = p2;

    p2.setX(bufer.at(i));
    p2.setY (sh+bufer.at(i+1));
    painter->drawLine(p1,p2);


   }

painter -> setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::red),12));

animationpoint.setX(0);
animationpoint.setY(sh +100);
painter->drawPoint(animationpoint);
}
```

А вот функция, которая готовит для графика данные

```
void MainWindow::MakeData(int value){
float x, y, point_x, point_y;

int mas_y;

const int size_x = width();
const int size_y = height()/6;

bufer.clear();

for (point_x = 0; point_x < size_x; point_x+=3){
    x = 30*point_x/size_x;

    switch(value){
    case 0: break;
    case 1: {
        y=sin(x);
        mas_y=4;
        break;
    };
    case 2: {

        y = 2*pow(x,2)-14*x;
        mas_y = 70;
        break;
    };
    case 3: {
        y = tan(x);
        mas_y = 500;
        break;
    };
    case 4: {
        y = atan(x);
        mas_y = 4;
        break;
    }

    };

    point_y = (size_y-(y+1)*size_y/mas_y);
    bufer << point_x << point_y;
    }
 }
```

Обработчик нажатия на кнопку

```
void MainWindow::painEventPath(){
QString str = "value1";
MakeData(str.remove(0,5).left(5).toInt());
this -> repaint();
startanimation->start(1000);

}
```

Comment: Покажите метод paintEvent

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Добавил

Comment: Может пригодится Animation Framework https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html

Comment: @magrif я читал об этом, но у меня-то не объект, а точка.

Comment: Наверное  delete   painter; а потом уже   painter = new QPainter(this);

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так все равно выдает QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1 каждый тик таймера

Comment: Я с QT знаком очень поверхностно, но  по логике painter должен быть инициализирован  конструктором, поскольку для одного виджета  устройство рисования должна быть одна и та же.  Это лишь мнение, другим ничем не смогу помочь...

Comment: Чё-то вы перемудрили. Возьмите стандартный пример про аналоговые часы и сделайте по аналогии, только с графиком. [Analog Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html). В документации кстати написано, что `repaint()` вызывать не круто, можно UB в некоторых случаях получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(...):... {

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&]() {
        // Cуть в том, чтобы сделать шаг для смещения точки
        animationpoint.setX(<Новый Х>);
        animationpoint.setY(<Новый Y>);

        update();    
    }

}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* evt) {

    QPainter painter(this); // Не надо указатель
    // ...

    Настройки для выдления точки цветом, формой, размерами    

    // Следующие две строчки держат вашу точку на одном месте. Видимо их надо удалить
    // animationpoint.setX(0);
    // animationpoint.setY(sh +100);

    painter.drawPoint(animationpoint);
}
```